# Animated movie (or series). A robot gives someone a flower. Floating islands

Tags: story-identification, movie, anime, cartoon

I remember a scene from a movie where like a iron golem or machine gives a person a flower and I think they were in a floating island.

Comment: We need more details. https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question will help you dredge up details. Also, please visit the [tour] to learn how to accept an answer.

Answer (score 28):

Could this be [***Laputa: Castle in the Sky***](https://ghibli.fandom.com/wiki/Castle_in_the_Sky)?

[Floating islands](https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/studio-ghibli/images/e/e7/Laputa.png/revision/latest/scale-to-width-down/1000?cb=20181216165211), check. [Robot giving someone a flower](https://tenor.com/view/castle-in-the-sky-castle-in-the-sky-gif-5203634), check.

Answer (score 12):

Laputa: Castle in the Sky has a floating island which is the home to some ancient rather large robots many of which are covered in moss. In one scene a robot presents the main character with a flower